# Visual Studio 2019 doesn't indent or have Intellisense in JavaScript after [Enter]

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2019, text-formatting, javascript-intellisense

VS 2019 Community 16.7.3.  When editing JavaScript, I finish a line, press [Enter] and the cursor goes to column 1 rather than keeping the indent. This used to work and still does if I'm editing C#.  I've tried resetting all options, deleting .suo and user files, changing indent options: none, block, smart, switching between tabs and spaces, but nothing changes.

Secondly, Intellisense doesn't work in JavaScript either. Code is not displayed and no color difference within the script tags.

How can I make the editor indent and intellisense work when writing JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Visual Studio Intellicode extension disabled, you may have to re-enable it.

I use `TypeScript` and when this happened it was because of a bug that when the Visual Studio Intellicode extension was disabled, the `TypeScript` editor would break and treat the files as a regular text file. After re-enabling the extension the editor worked as expected. I'm unsure if it affects the `JavaScript` editor. [Here is a link to the submitted issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1158488/disabling-intellicode-2273331896-breaks-typescript.html).

Comment: I explicitly enabled Intellicode for Javascript and disabled the EditorConfig inference but still doing the same thing.

Comment: My experience: Intellisense dereferencing suggestions for TypeScript stopped working for me today in 16.11.19. I had IntelliCode and its bloat already disabled. Enabling IntelliCode, restarting VS and reloading the solution, then disabling IntelliCode and restarting VS resolved the issue. Bizarre.